# AngularJs - Find an object in an array by key and display its value in View

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have an object array:

```
$scope.objArr = [{key:1,value:'value1'},{key:2,value:'value2'},{key:3,value:'value3'}];
```

And a variable that should map to `key`. For example:

```
$scope.a = 3;
```

With both in Controller I want to display the `value` in View. The above example should give me "value3."

Without creating another function, I do something like:

```
<span ng-repeat="obj in objArr | filter:{key:a}:true">{{obj.value}}</span>
```

It works but using `ng-repeat` feels wrong. Is there any better way (without creating another function)?

**EDIT:**

This is the full code I'm using:

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <span ng-repeat="obj in objArr | filter:{key:a.test}:true">{{obj.value}}</span>
        <input ng-model="a.test"/>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController',function($scope){
  $scope.objArr = [{key:1,value:'value1'},{key:2,value:'value2'},{key:3,value:'value3'}];
  $scope.a = {test:2}
});
```

It is initially showing "value2", but shows nothing after I change the value of the input field. Why is that?

Comment: Did you consider storing objArr as actual key value pairs? {1: 'val1', 2: 'val2'}

Comment: I might need to re-order the array without affecting the key-value mapping.

Comment: ng-repate itself is sort of function iterating through each item. So if you want to eliminate using ng-repate you will need to use a function to filter results.

Comment: So you are saying no angularjs default functions for this? Why after changing the variable value nothing shows in my example?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. [please have a look at this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LoVcSA9fb41tECOdbaIm?p=preview) and clarify your problem. It seems that it's working fine.

Comment: @KhalidHussain: He needs an alternative method other than `ng-repeat`. He feel that `ng-repeat` is not the best way to do this.

Comment: And using `ng-repeat` has a problem. See my updated question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

you can create a method inside your controller

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

 myApp.controller('MyController',function($scope){
    $scope.objArr = [{key:1,value:'value1'},{key:2,value:'value2'},{key:3,value:'value3'}];
    $scope.callSearch = function(num) {
    var abc = filterFilter($scope.objArr, {id: num});
    $scope.item= abc[0].value;
  };
});
```

In your View you can do this

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <input ng-model="search"/>
  <button ng-click="callSearch(search);">Search</button>
 {{item}}  
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way without involving creating another function in controller?